# Does the definition "needs to be at least XX bytes long" include the null terminator, or should I use XX+1?

Tags: c, manpage

I was wondering, when you see an API that says that a character buffer should be *at least* XXX byte long, does it include the null terminating character?
Not that I mind sparing a byte, but this thing bugs me... (no double meaning here!)

From the Mac OS X manpage for `if_indextoname`:

> The if_indextoname() function maps the interface index specified in ifindex to it corresponding name,
>        which is copied into the buffer pointed to by ifname, which must be of at least IFNAMSIZ bytes.

Comment: It has to be minimum XX, as it says.

Comment: I'll bet my money that  IFNAMSIZ includes the `\0` character.

Comment: Thanks EugeneSh. , so you're basically saying: YES, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character buffer is a `NUL` terminated string. Therefore the buffer needs to be large enough to hold the string, including the `NUL`.